# Why does my UINavigationBar change colors when I run my app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4.5

I'm building an iPad app using storyboards.  In Interface Builder (XCode 4.5), the nav bar is the default (light grey) color...

[image]

However, when I run the app, it changes color to a dark grey...

[image]

Has anyone else had this problem?  No matter what color I set it to in Interface Builder, it always ends up dark grey when I run it.

Thanks so much in advance for your wisdom!

Comment: is it occurs in only ios6 or in all ios????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS 6 the status bar have the same color as the navigation bar.
You can customize that, according to the answers to this question:
[How to change Statusbar on Modal Views iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512666/how-to-change-statusbar-on-modal-views-ios-6)

Answer (score 1):

You can colorize your navigation bar with the following line of code, just use it and you nav bar is always light gray:

```
[[navController navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
```

When you set the navigation bar color in interface builder, this only affects the view you get in IB itself, it is only a design help. The real color you have to set in code.