# How to change statusbar tint color with hidden navigationcontroller in iOS 6.0?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uistatusbar

I've uinavigationcontroller and within uiviewcontroller. Now my `navigationbarhidden = yes`.
But when I hide the navigation bar then changed the color of the status bar.
I want to change the color of the status bar as color of the hidden navigation bar.
I did so :

[image]

I haven`t used navigation controller anywhere as shown in the picture. This is just hack way in iOS6, but it only changed color for views which are not in a  navigation controller. For me though, solution is important only in iOS6

Any idea?

Comment: Do you want status bar color as it is in Navigation bar tint color??

Answer (score 0):

**Change StatusBar color**

[image]

**For Hide navigationBar**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: now, what if navigationBarHidden = NO. I had a  problem with that: the color of satus bar hasn't changed!?

Comment: in someplace navigationBarHidden = NO, in someplace navigationBarHidden = YES.

Answer (score 0):

As has been answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467794/how-to-set-status-bar-tint-color-on-ios-6):

In your "Project Summary", in "Status Bar", set "Style" and "Tinting" to "Default.
Then, jump into you xib or storyboard and add a UINavigationBar just bellow the status bar.
Set the UINavigationBar "Style" to "Default" and select the "Tinting" of your choice.
Run! :-)

If you don't want any UINavigationBar visible in your Interface, all you want to do is putting the UINavigationBar behind all the Objects, or set the "Alpha" to zero.

Comment: This isn't a solution. It's a hack that brings about the desired result at the cost of adding an unnecessary UI element, which is confusing to anyone who looks at the xib file, and also makes it difficult to work with other UI elements near the top of the screen.