# Is it possible to set the Status Bar tint color, even though the navigationBar is hidden?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I've searched on Apple docs and other similar questions here, but none of them helped me solve my problem under iOS 6.0.

I'm setting my `UINavigationController` on AppDelegate like so:

```
UINavigationController *nav;
nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:_myViewController];
nav.navigationBar.tintColor = [self myTintColor];
nav.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

During the application launch it shows the Status Bar tint color, because I've set it up on my Target summary, like shown in this picture:

[image]

If I don't hide the `navigationBar` the Status Bar tint color persists, otherwise it doesn't. Is it possible to set the  Status Bar tint color, even though the `navigationBar` is hidden at launch time?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making your navigation bar hidden, you can change its alpha to 0 as suggested here: [How to set status bar tint color on iOS 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467794/how-to-set-status-bar-tint-color-on-ios-6)