# UIStatusBar Color same as UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uicolor, uistatusbar

I'm looking for a simple thing, but it seems harder then i thought!
I want to change the StatusBar color of my iPhone to be the exact same solid color as my NavigationBar. Kind of the same principle as in iOS7, but now in iOS6

Anyone who could help me out?
This is the code i'm using now, but the problem here is that the statusbar gets an other color because of a shade.

```
UINavigationBar *navigationBarAppearance = [UINavigationBar appearance];
[navigationBarAppearance setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationbar_background"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

Thanks

Comment: Your navigation bar have Image not color .. :)

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467794/how-to-set-status-bar-tint-color-on-ios-6

Comment: That is not working out for me, as i mentioned. My ToolBar color is already changed. But it is not changed in the color i want. Now it is some dark blue, but i want it to be the same blue as my navigationbar.

Answer (score 1):

[image: change using option in project summary]

You could probably choose default behaviour from here.

Comment: This is only at startup :-(